# Why do electric moments in piezoelectric crystals have a random distribution of orientations to begin with?

Tags: piezoelectric

[image]

Above is just one picture used to visualize the piezoelectric effect. The explanation usually is that as an electric field is applied to the material, the electric moments of the molecules in the material (initially pointing at random directions) attempt to align according to the applied field, and therefore mechanical stress occurs as the molecules realign. But at least many piezoelectric material used, such as quartz, are *crystals*, and crystals by definition have a regular lattice structure. So shouldn't the electric dipole moments be pointing in the same direction to begin with, if we are indeed talking about crystals?

Comment: But is your piezo material a _single_ crystal? Often not, so one is applying stress to the polycrystalline grains with various orientations.

Comment: Even in "single" crystals you can get domains. This occurs because there are many choices of orientations and even the smallest defects will push local areas to orient differently

Comment: @JonCuster Ah, I see! That makes sense, thank you!